# Complete product list in cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, inventory, advanced-search

We have a link to the complete inventory of magento, the link goes to a cms page and we have added this code inside:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

We see all inventory and we can  sort by:, View as:, show:,

The number of page doesn't appears and we need it to navigate truth all inventory, we have more than 150 product and it is not possible to view in the same page.

We also try to add advanced search in left, but when we search things, the advanced search find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to add **dynamic** content in a **static** CMS block, that's not what they are built for. The problem here is that

1.) you need an additional toolbar block for pagination and

2.) the content of a static block is cached and it does not have any parameters, so you cannot cache different content based on the current page etc.

So your best option is to create a module with its own controller and use the same layout updates as `catalog_category_default` of `catalog.xml` (or `catalog_category_layered` if you want to add layered navigation). Since you don't set a current category in your controller, the product list block should show all products, like in your current code.